# how many types of strings in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

How many types of string classes are there in visual c++. I got confused when i was going through the msdn center.

I found this type under the namespace system
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=VS.71).aspx

and then in the headers section, i found the string header definitions. This seemed different from the above. One thing i noticed, this one comes under the STL.
(pls see the comment for the link, i cant post two links in the same post)

which one is normally used? I'm finding a hard time getting around with the different string classes

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syxtdd4f(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different libraries come with different string types:

In plain old C you would use `char*`, the C++ standard library provides `std::string` which is widely used in C++ development. (string is defined as `typedef basic_string<char> string;`)

Microsoft created the MFC `CString` class which is (was?) used in MFC style programming, Qt has its `QString` which is used in Qt programs. What you're mentioning with `System.String` is a .net string class which can only be used in Managed code (with .net).

I'd suggest to stick with `std::string` `(#include <string>`) if you're new to C++. It's standard and platform independent.

Comment: thanks for clearing tat now :) another question. I cant find a function to convert my std::string to lowercase. Its not in the member function of #include<string>

Comment: @Jay Ther's std::tolower to turn characters into lower case. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/tolower/

Comment: Also worth mentioning `std::wstring`, which is defined as `typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring;`. This works the same as with a `std::string` but will use wide (usually 16-bit) characters. This is useful if you're building on for example, Windows, and compiling with UNICODE defined, as you will retain compatibility with the WinAPI functions.

Comment: hey thanks a lot everybody. All your comments were absolutely useful :)

Comment: In addition to my previous comment (which I can't seem to edit now), if you're using `std::wstring` then your string literals should be defined as: `std::wstring str(L"A Wide String")`.  The "L" makes the literal string wide.  Windows uses the macro `_T` to define a string based on whether you're building a Unicode application, and I usually have a similar macro in my own code.

Answer (score 3):

String types in common use in Microsoft code are char*, wchar_t*, LPSTR, LPTSTR, LPWSTR, LPCSTR, LPCTSTR, LPCWSTR, BSTR, OLESTR, UNICODE_STRING, String, string, wstring, _bstr_t, CString

The last 5 are classes.  You pick the one that gives you the least conversion headaches, depending on what API you need to use:

- std::string and wstring, standard C++ library
- System::String, the string type for managed code
- _bstr_t, wrapper for a BSTR, used in COM automation
- CString, string type for the ATL and MFC libraries.

You're likely to encounter additional string types when you work with other APIs.